# Creating a Pop-Up form in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to create a windows form that gets displayed for 2 seconds when triggerd by an event, and then closes automatically.

I have tried several options. This is my current code:

```
        this.aletPopup.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.aletPopup.Show();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        this.aletPopup.Close();
```

This preforms the actions that I desire, however, when the form loads it does not load the label or image which is on the form. Instead, the area where the image and label are become transparent. My desired output is this: 
[image]

I have also tried using `this.aletPopup.ShowDialog();`, which does display the graphics. However, the form will not close automatically when using this method.

**EDIT:** I am attempting to use 
Michael Perrenoud's solution. However, I cannot get the form to close. I have a timer set at a 2000ms interval which is initally disabled. Am I overriding the OnShown correctly?

```
public AlertPopForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void closingTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        closingTimer.Enabled = false;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void AlertPopForm_OnShown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        closingTimer.Enabled = true;
        closingTimer.Start(); 
    }
```

Comment: You are not overriding `OnShown` at all. it should look somthing like `protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e) { base.OnShown(e); /*Your code here*/ }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead, how about leveraging `ShowDialog`, and then using a `Timer` on the dialog form. In the `Tick` event of the `Timer`, close the form.

```
this.aletPopup.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
this.aletPopup.ShowDialog();
```

You could even pass the interval into the `.ctor` of the dialog form if you wanted some flexibility.

It's very important to note here that you'd need to leverage the [`OnShown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onshown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) override to actually `Start` the `Timer` so the form is in fact shown to the user.

Comment: I tried this (should have mentioned it in my post), however, the form would never open.

Comment: @AdamJakiela, that's not quite accurate. If you leverage the [OnShown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onshown(v=vs.110).aspx) override you can control when the `Timer` starts. Here it wouldn't start until the form was in fact shown.

Comment: I am attempting to use the timer, however the application will not close. I have posted my code above.

Comment: @AdamJakiela, is the `Tick` handler being entered?

Answer (score 1):

The reason can be in Message Loop. When you block your thread by Thread.Sleep, it also blocks Message loop.

You can make like this:

```
this.aletPopup.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
this.aletPopup.Show();
for(var i = 0; i<= 200; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);
    Application.DoEvents();
}
this.aletPopup.Close();
```

[DoEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will process messages from message queue during that time.

Comment: Can someone explain why this was down-voted? Seemed to work for me.

Comment: The use of Application.DoEvents is a horrible idea here, and an entire abuse of what it is designed to do.  It is introducing subtle bugs/race conditions and advocating very poor programming practices.  It will also wait for an indeterminiate amount of time, very likely quite a bit longer than it should be, due to the imprecision of `Thread.Sleep` along with the fact that you are not counting any time spent waiting on messages being processed.  On most machines, `Sleep` will have a minimum precision of 16ms, so this'll be waiting for at least 3 seconds.

Comment: This is definately ANSWERING the question... but the solution is bad.

Comment: well, yeah. i also agree, that it's not the best solution.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov It's not just "not the best", it's actively harmful as a solution, and it is irresponsible to propose using it.

Comment: I can argue it. I agree that it can take more than 2 seconds, if there are some messages that requires more time to process. Why it's harmful? In exactly this case. Jeff Atwood agrees that it's not good solution, but sometimes it makes sense - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/is-doevents-evil.html.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov It is a tool that should really only be used by someone who understand the exact implications of it's use, is prepared to support them, and is capable of dealing with problems that may arise due to unforeseen implications.  Very few people fit that; basically no new programmers will.  It is actively harmful in that it can introduce subtle and hard to understand bugs/behavior; it is re-entrant, can easily result in stack overflows, etc.  Also, there doesn't even need to be pending messages for this to take longer, on most machines it'll be waiting for at least 3 seconds anyway.

Comment: I agree with you that sometimes it can lead to strange behavior, if someone doesn't know how windows message loop works, and what are drawbacks there. ok, thanks for description. BTW: 3 seconds can be easily fixed by decreasing iteration count and make thread.sleep like 50 milliseconds :)

Answer (score 1):

When calling `Thread.Sleep` you're blocking the UI thread, thus preventing it from processing UI events.

You need to ensure that `Close` is called after 2 seconds without actually blocking the main thread.  There are a number of ways of doing this, such as using a `Timer`, or something like `Task.Delay`:

```
aletPopup.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
aletPopup.Show();
Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
    .ContinueWith(t => aletPopup.Close(), 
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening, is that you are halting the thread that draws the form.  So the form has time to display, but as it's being drawn, the thread is being stopped.

Easy enough to fix....

Add an event handler to the popup for the `Load` event with the following handler:

```
private async void handleLoad(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  await Task.Delay(2000);
  Close();
}
```

**Remark**
Because you used `Show()`, the user could always click around this popup.  If this is undesirable, then use `ShowDialog()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try a refresh to redraw the form?

```
    this.aletPopup.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    this.aletPopup.Show();

    this.alertPopup.Refresh();


    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    this.aletPopup.Close();
```

Comment: This will still freeze the entire applications UI for two seconds, making it unresponsive.